# How to assign value to GoogleMap

Tags: java, android, google-maps

How do i assign a value to `GoogleMap mMap;`

it is showing null pointer exception when trying to run my activity and i think that means i have to assign a value to `mMap` how do i do that

this is the error i am getting

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
```

this is my code

```
public class RideHailActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener
{
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 7000;
    private final int PLAY_SERVICES_RES_REQUEST = 7001;

    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private Location lastLocation;

    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
    private static int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 3000;
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10;

    DatabaseReference reference;
    GeoFire geoFire;

    Marker current;

    MaterialAnimatedSwitch locationSwitch;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ride_hail);


        MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mapFragment != null) mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        locationSwitch = (MaterialAnimatedSwitch)findViewById(R.id.location_switch);
        locationSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MaterialAnimatedSwitch.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(boolean isOnline) {
                if (isOnline) {
                    startLocationUpdates();
                    displayLocation();
                }else {
                    stopLocationUpdates();
                    current.remove();
                }
            }
        });

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("biker");
        geoFire = new GeoFire(reference);

        setUpLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults [0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (checkPlayServices()) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                        createLocationRequest();

                        if (locationSwitch.isChecked()) displayLocation();
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private void setUpLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            },MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }else {
            if (checkPlayServices()) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                createLocationRequest();

                if (locationSwitch.isChecked()) displayLocation();
            }
        }
    }

    private void createLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
    }

    private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, PLAY_SERVICES_RES_REQUEST).show();
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void stopLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
    }

    private void displayLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        if (lastLocation != null) {
            if (locationSwitch.isChecked()) {
                final double latitude = lastLocation.getLatitude();
                final double longitude = lastLocation.getLongitude();

                geoFire.setLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(), new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                        if (current != null) current.remove();


                        current = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_bike))
                                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                                .title("You"));

                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude),15.0f));
                        rotateMarker(current, -360, mMap);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Cannot get your location");
        }
    }

    private void rotateMarker(final Marker current, final float i, GoogleMap googleMap) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final float startRotation = current.getRotation();
        final long duration = 1500;

        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float)elapsed/duration);
                float rot = t*i+(1-t)*startRotation;
                current.setRotation(-rot >180?rot/2:rot);
                if (t<1.0) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this,16);

                }
            }
        });

        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        displayLocation();
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lastLocation = location;
        displayLocation();
    }
}
```

thanks is advance

Comment: Consider adding code of what you have already

Comment: @Thompsonsparta SORRY i added my code now

Comment: @Thompsonsparta i am getting the error on `mMap.addMarker` under  `diplaylocation` method

Answer (score 0):

In your activity activity Xml,add a Mapview then initialize

```
MapView mMapView;
static final GoogleMap[] googleMap = new GoogleMap[1];
static LatLng mypos = new LatLng(0, 0);

 void init_map(final Activity act, Bundle saved_inst)
{
    //you need to have intialized mMapview from your layout
    mMapView.onCreate(saved_inst);
    mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately


    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            googleMap[0] = mMap;

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(act, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(act, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(act,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        99);
            } else {
                googleMap[0].setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                        mypos = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(mypos).zoom(10).build();
                        googleMap[0].animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


                    }
                });
                googleMap[0].setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapLoaded() {



                    }
                });
                googleMap[0].setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                googleMap[0].setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

            }


        }

    });
}
```

you then call it like this from your oncreate

```
 init_map(this,savedInstanceState);
```

this is assuming you have already set the api key from the manifest

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="your_api_key" />
```

to get started on geting an API key see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key

Comment: Is there an easier way to assign a value to `mMap`